# On-board surround sound

Tags: 14.04, sound

I'm using my on-board soundchip with a S/PDIF output to a 5.1 sound kit.
Trying to enable 5.1 sound, I followed these instructions :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio

During the speaker test, everything works fine, I can hear sound from all my speakers.
However, in practical test cases, for instance playing a movie in VLC, I generally get no sound, and in the rare cases I do, it's still stereo.

I ended up on this question that was asked a year ago, and never received any answer :
[Surround sound woes with 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470449/surround-sound-woes-with-14-04)

My problem is entirely identical. And indeed, keeping pavucontrol open does solve my problem too. Obviously, this is not a real solution.

I'd like to re-open this question : Does anyone know what causes this, and/or a decent fix or workaround that I can apply ?

Thanks.